# If $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z-1|=1$ then prove $\arg(z-1)=2\arg z$

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z-1|=1$ then which of the following is correct 
>   \begin{align}
> &a)\quad \arg(z-1)=2\arg z\\
> &b)\quad 2\arg z=2/3.\arg(z^2-z)\\
> &c)\quad \arg(z-1)=\arg(z+1)\\
> &d)\quad \arg z=2\arg(z+1)
> \end{align}

**My Attempt**
$$
(x-1)^2+y^2=1\implies
$$
$$
\arg(z-1)=\alpha=\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x-1}\\
2\arg z=2\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2y}{x}.\frac{x^2}{x^2-y^2}=\tan^{-1}\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}
$$

As it was asked as a multiple choice question, can I easily solve it using geometry ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the points $O = 0 + 0i$, $A = -1 + 0i$, $B = 1 + 0i$, and $C = z - 1$. Note that $\arg z$ is the angle $BAC$, and $\arg(z - 1)$ is the angle $BOC$. Now apply the theorem from circle geometry about angles subtended from the centre being double the angle subtended from the circumference.

Comment: If somebody else has the time to create an image to complement this, I'll delete and give a +1.

Comment: Feel free to add this to your answer https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xzjw20kgyo

Comment: Can you also prood b) by this approach or do you need another for that?

Answer (score 1):

the geometric argument is neater, but the following manipulation using the double-angle formula for the cosine is standard, and worth being acquainted with.

$$
z = 1 + e^{i\theta}
$$

so
$$
\arg (z-1) = \arg e^{i\theta} = \theta
$$

and

$$
\arg z = \arg (1+\cos \theta + i\sin \theta) \\
= \arg \left( 2 \cos \frac{\theta}2 \left(\cos \frac{\theta}2+ i \sin \frac{\theta}2 \right)\right) \\
= \frac{\theta}2
$$

Comment: What is the general form of the double angle formula you use (and where can I read it, do you have some link or anything) and how does the last equality follow?